# WCF Azure Hosted Client using Service Bus and Castle Windsor in console app

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, castle-windsor, azureservicebus

Hi I'm trying to get dependency injection to work using Castle Windsor in a console app to host WCF service in Azure using the example in:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/

My WCF service works fine using Castle Windsor (Small sample):

```
 public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {
    private readonly IPersonManager _personManager;

    public PersonService(IPersonManager personManager)
    {
        _personManager = personManager;
    }

    public Message Create(Person person)
    {
        Message result = _ personManager.Create(person);
    }
}
```

Castle Windsor (in wcf service Global.asax)

```
private void BuildWindsorContainer ()
{
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
container.Kernel.Register(
Component.For< IPersonManager >().ImplementedBy<PersonManager >(),
Component.For<IPersonService>()
    .ImplementedBy<PersonService>()
    .Named("WebS.PersonService"),
);
}
```

In My hosted Client which calls the WCF service I have:

```
private static ServiceHost CallPersonService()
{
BuildWindsorContainer ();

var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof (PersonService));

sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IPersonService), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:37050/person");

sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IPersonService), new NetTcpRelayBinding(),
ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", ServiceNamespace, "person"))
.Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
{
    TokenProvider =
        TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", Key)
});

private void BuildWindsorContainer ()
{
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
container.Kernel.Register(
Component.For< IPersonManager >().ImplementedBy<PersonManager >(),
Component.For<IPersonService>()
.ImplementedBy<PersonService>()
.Named("WebS.PersonService"),
);
}
```

How do I get the dependencies to be injected into service from the client?

```
var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof (PersonService));
sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IPersonService), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:37050/person");
```

IPersonManager is null in service when the client runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var sh = (ServiceHost)new DefaultServiceHostFactory()
    .CreateServiceHost(typeof(PersonService).AssemblyQualifiedName, new Uri[] { });
```